# Is there an after render event for Highchart bubble legend clicks?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

For a Highchart bubble chart I've got a hook in the chart events for render such that it looks at the bubble and datalabel and that relocates the datalabel when an overlap with another label occurs. It also figures out the x,y of the bubble and datalabel and draws a leader line from the label to the bubble. That works pretty well except for the case when the legend item is clicked to filter the bubbles. When Highcharts moves stuff around in this case, the render event series data has the x,y values from BEFORE the move which goofs up where the lines are drawing to.

Optimally, I'd like like know when the chart is completed renderering after the legend filter changes, then I can run the same logic to avoid collisions. At the moment, the collision logic I have is getting the location values before the legend filter process has laid out the elements. When I debug and toggle on/off the legend filter I see the new location in the series point datalabels so it leads me to believe the new values are there after the legend filter layout does it's thing.

Comment: Hi @Miro Perez, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editro? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/ Maybe an animation is the problem?

Comment: I'll try and setup a simple scenario today. I thought I already tried to turn off animations and that didnt have any f/x.  Because I was curious I put a defer in the render event of 1 second then executed my code and that seems to work but I don't want to introduce a timing issue either.

Comment: Ok, please also try to disable `defer` option: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.dataLabels.defer

Comment: Here's a rough sample to illustrate what I'm seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/ysd2cv5x/3/ . When it first draws it offsets the x, y by the amounts in the render event. However click the Series 2 legend and you will see that it rerenders but doesn't go thru the render event code again. The logic is not the final translate logic but it shows what I'm seeing locally without all the code. If you uncomment the alert() in the render event, you can see it does get called on the series legend click but then another render occurs after it.

Comment: I wonder if there is some other event I can listen for after that legend series click. The only thing I saw was a legendItemClick but thats just to cancel the click event if you return false

Comment: I think I figured it out. It was the top level animation on the chart prop that was causing it. It's commented at the moment in the fiddle. Thanks again for pointing out animation might be the issue.